# Singularities of $\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}+i\frac{\sinh(2y)}{cos(2x)-cosh(2y)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find the singularities of the following complex-valued function:

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}+i\frac{\sinh(2y)}{cos(2x)-cosh(2y)}$$

One idea I had was to somehow write everything in terms of $z$, but I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's not $$f(z) = \frac{\sin (2x)\sinh (2y)}{(\cosh (2y) - \cos (2x))^2} + i\frac{2\cosh (2y)\cos (2x) - 2}{(\cosh (2y) - \cos (2x))^2}\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, the real part is given as $\frac{sin(2x)}{cosh(2y)-cos(2x)}$. It obeys the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.

Comment: In that case, from the question I asked, you may be inclined to suspect that the given $f$ is not meromorphic.

Comment: @DanielFischer So there are no singularities?

Comment: Wait. I don't think $f$ satisfies the CR equations. Let me check my computations on paper.

Comment: I forgot a factor of $2$ above, but I still get that the given $f$ doesn't satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I found my mistake. I am editing the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin (2x) - i\sinh (2y)}{\cosh (2y) - \cos (2x)} = \frac{\sin (2x) - \sin (2iy)}{\cosh (2y) - \cos (2x)} = \frac{\sin (2x) - \sin (2iy)}{\cos (2iy) - \cos (2x)}.$$

Now use the identities

$$\sin A - \sin B = 2 \cos \frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$$

and

$$\cos A - \cos B = -2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$$

to simplify and obtain an expression of $f$ that is easier to analyse.